# Too may 'zu's in zu infinitive

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality, infinitive, separable-verb

I came across this in a game I'm playing (Stardew Valley):

> Dann brauchst du noch einen Kohleklumpen, um das Feuer zu anzufachen.

There seems to be one too many *zu*'s in the last clause, so it should really read *um das Feuer anzufachen*, or with a different verb something like *um das Feuer zu schüren*. Is this a typographical error, some kind of regionalism, or is having *zu* twice allowed in some circumstances? DWDS does list *zufächeln* as a verb, but I don't think it fit's the context.

Note, the same sentence from the English edition of the game is "You'll need a lump of coal to fuel the fire."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, this sentence is wrong. I don't think this is a regionalism or sociolect. I guess it is just an editing mistake - most probably another verb was used before and the superfluous *zu* was not removed after editing.

Correct would be:

> Dann brauchst du noch einen Kohleklumpen, um das Feuer anzufachen.

Comment: Fair enough, that's what I suspected. Someday I may be fluent enough to say that what I think is wrong is definitely wrong, but I'm not there yet. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it was _zu entfachen_ before.

Comment: @phipsgabler I have thought so, too. I didn't include in the answer, since it is mere speculation and not really relevant to the question. But I agree.